# Child theme problem

Tags: child-theme, css

I'm trying to add a child theme on a website, I created the folder called mythemename-child,  I created the style.css file with this information inside:

```
/*
 Theme Name: Mizrahi-child
 Theme URI: http://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes
 Description: Your theme description.
 Author: Matteo Schiatti
 Author URI: http://www.templatemonster.com/
 Template:     mizrahi
 Version:      1.0.0
 License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Text Domain: mizrahi
 Tags: one-column, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-menu, featured-images, post-formats, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
*/
```

After I created the function.php file with this content:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

I can see the child theme in the back office but when I activate it the site lose all the css.

I can't understand why, I tried also with the @import method on the style.css file but nothing:

@import url("../twentyfifteen/style.css");

I added this code on my function.php:

```
    <?php

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/magnific-popup.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/magnific-popup.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/material-icons.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/material-icons.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/slider-pro.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/slider-pro.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/swiper.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/swiper.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/plugins/booked.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/plugins/builder.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/plugins/restaurant-menu.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/buttons.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/elements.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/footer.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/forms.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/header.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/menus.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/misc.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/navigation.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/post.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/site/social.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/widgets/about.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/widgets/custom-post.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/widgets/instagram.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/widgets/subscribe.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic/widgets/widget-default.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/rtl.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the **comments**, the name of the CSS must be unique. You named every CSS with 'parent-style'. Each must have a different name.

Like so:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style1', get_template_directory_uri().'/style1.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style2', get_template_directory_uri().'/style2.css' );
```

The code

```
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Is used if the theme has **ALL** of it styles inside the main **style.css**. In most of the cases, that doesn't work, because templates have more CSS inside another directories.

You will probably have to do something like:

```
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/another-style.css' );
}
```

And if you need to have your own CSS file, you need to enqueue it **AFTER** the parent

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
```

Enqueue the secondary styles first, and the main styles **AFTER** them.

Make sure the 'add_action' is called **AFTER** you create the function.

Comment: Standard themes such as twenty* do have all stylesheets in style.css

Comment: He is not using twenty*. Only the basic templates have that. And as I said: "In most of the cases"  =)

Comment: You are right, I (mostly) saw the the last import-line

Comment: It happens. All good. =)

Comment: I edited my question with the new code of my function.php file. I tried to activate the child theme now but the result is worse than before. I put in the code all the css that I found in the assest folder. What do you mean with "And if you need to have your own CSS file, you need to enqueue it AFTER the parent"? I have a style.css in my child theme folder and I want to use just it to modify the css.

Comment: You need to enqueue your style after you enqueue the parent style. Even if your style is 'style.css', inside the child thmee directory, you need to enqueue it.
I'll take a look at your new code.

Comment: Try to enqueue the parent 'style.css' and 'rtl.css' at the end.
And try to put the 'add_action' after you creat the function. Cuz it doesn't make sense to add an action that calls a function before creating the function.

Comment: I edited my question with the new code, I tried to enqueue rtl.css and style.css at the end and I moved add_action but nothing changed. Any advice?

Comment: I rly can't see what might be the problem, except that every stylesheet you named 'parent-style'. That might cause problems.
Can you try, or do you want to, use a plugin? If yes, try [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/)

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Am unable to comment and ask qns, so done as answer. Point 3 below does identify an error; the rest I expect you've covered. I've also added my own working enqueuer (but I only needed style.css)

1. ensure the value specified for "Template:" at the top of your CSS matches the value for "Theme:" in parent's CSS
2. View HTML source of page from your browser. What styles if any are listed in "html under <head>? This info may help with answers.
3. [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) says the first argument/parameter of wp_enqueue_style **must be a unique** "handle" (name); **but in your last example you use 'parent-style' as the handle for every style sheet**.
4. check parent's functions.php and see exactly what is being "enqueued".
5. if its any help, this is code that works for me from my Hemingway child functions.php (I only need style.css). Note I am not using a string 'parent_style' but  variable $parent_style which has been assigned a value. The WP Codex link above explains other settings used.

   ```
   function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
     $parent_style = 'hemingway_style';
     wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
   ```
6. In answer to your question by enqueuing child CSS last you ensures that where Child and Parent CSS rules conflict then the CSS rules will be used by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try This example:

```
Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique

function example_enqueue_styles() {

        // enqueue parent styles
        wp_enqueue_style('style-1', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

        // enqueue child styles
        wp_enqueue_style('style-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array('parent-theme'));

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_styles');
```

in your code  `wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style<-"this must be unique"', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/dynamic.css' );`